# Which naming convention should I use for a struct?

Tags: c, winapi, struct, naming-conventions

In plain C, I will name a `struct` like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int something;
};
```

But, since I'm now programming under Windows, I want my code to be very consistent in which refers to naming conventions. So, my variables are now named using `mixedCase` instead of `lower_case` and my functions are now using `CapWords`. I have seen some structs with all capital letters, but I don't like this very much because I reserve that for constants and macros.

Thanks.

Comment: This question, as it is stated, invites a lot of opinion.  As long as you stay away from reserved or keyword names, such as SOMETHING_t (where using the `_t` as a suffix is a little touchy sometimes), or `struct` _struct_  .  I favor (even though you do not) `typedef struct {...}ANY_NAME;//using caps.`  Then use `ANY_NAME` to create instances like this:  ANY_NAME any, *pAny;

Comment: So should I use `ALL_CAPS`, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a single naming convention used even within only the Windows SDK - so you might be able to justify whatever you like with .

Answer (score 4):

Check out this link if you want a reference on Naming Conventions in C.

As long as you're consistent with using CamelCase of under_score conventions for whatever purpose, it doesn't really matter.

[What are the most common naming conventions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722112/what-are-the-most-common-naming-conventions-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your answer what I'm taking about WinAPI programming.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar question: 
[Naming convention for Win32/MFC with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499878/naming-convention-for-win32-mfc-with-c) 
MSDN naming guideline locates at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx
Struct naming convention is described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx