# this-> to reference everything

Tags: c++

I've recently spent a lot of time with javascript and am now coming back to C++. When I'm accessing a class member from a method I feed inclined to prefix it with `this->`.

```
class Foo {

  int _bar;

public:  
  /* ... */

  void setBar(int bar) {
    this->_bar = bar;
    // as opposed to
    _bar = bar;
  }
}
```

On reading, it saves me a brain cycle when trying to figure out where it's coming from.
Are there any reasons I shouldn't do this?

Comment: That extra brain cycle is saved by reading the function name.

Comment: Yes -- because to others who are actually accustomed to C++, it will take even more extra brain cycles, trying to figure out whether you think you're writing something where `this->` is actually needed, or you're just ignorant.

Comment: @chris There are other circumstances where the method might be more complicated than a getter/setter.

Comment: @RyanAmos, True, but the function name should always suffice to mostly know what it's doing.

Comment: @chris Maybe so for the result, but not the clever implementation.

Comment: @RyanAmos, Anything seen as clever should probably have a comment :)

Comment: @RyanAmos: For the clever implementation you need comments, not `this->`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And `this->` somehow excludes comments? Adding `this->` can only make things more clear. If you don't like `this->`, find&replace "this->" with "".

Comment: @RyanAmos: No, you can have both comments to explain the code and `this->`, but the complexity of the code is not a reason to add `this->` as your previous comment seemed to imply.

Comment: @RyanAmos:  OP suggests `this->` all the time as a means of documentation.  Using `this->` is not needed in any but a few unusual circumstances.  In those unusual circumstances, documentation in the form of comments could be considered as required.  Using `this->` in addition to the comments would not hurt, but `this->` is not a replacement for comments.  `this->` is generally only needed when name hiding is taking place, which is something I would classify as a **defect**, not cleverness.  Using `this->` in those cases doesn't explain why the names were hidden. "Why" is why we need comments

Comment: Using `this->` to denote member variable access is merely a matter of style.  You should be consistent in your style in a given project.  Using a non-needed `this->` as a convention in a project does not generate a *defect*, it just is a different convention.  And yes, people get very religious about such conventions.

Comment: See also: [Why use prefixes on member variables in C++ classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228161).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using this-> for class variables is perfectly acceptable.

However, don't start identifiers with an underscore, or include any identifiers with double underscore `__` anywhere.  There are some classes of reserved symbols that are easy to hit if you violate either of these two rules of thumb.  (In particular, _IdentifierStartingWithACapital is reserved by the standard for compilers).

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and a lower case letter are not reserved though, so this is not an issue.

Comment: @delnan: people forgetting the rules _is_ an issue.  So as Yakk explains, some classes of reserved symbols are easy to hit if you violate the rule of thumb: don't start identifiers with an underscore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: @delnan, One small fix on that: They are in the global scope. We're talking about class scope here, but one could extrapolate that.

Comment: To some people (including me), "class variable" is a static member.

Comment: IMO, "perfectly acceptable" is overstating things. The *compiler* won't complain, but you should write your code to be readable by other programmers, not just the compiler. From that viewpoint, it's clearly a bad practice and should definitely be avoided.

Comment: The acceptance of this answer is an example of what Paul Simon once sang, "A man hears what he wants to hear and disregards the rest."

Comment: @Yakk: -1:  I'd consider myself to be a competent programmer, and yet it would slow me down because I would be thinking "why would he have needed `this->` here?  Is there a name hidden?" And then I'd have to examine the code carefully.

Comment: @JohnDibling because it disagrees with your style: if `this->` is used consistently in a project for member variables, you wouldn't keep thinking that, would you?  It isn't a style I love, but it is only a style issue.

Comment: @Yakk:  I disagree.  There *is* something wrong with using `this->` as documentation.  It documents the wrong thing.  See my answer.

Comment: @John You would be confused if an entire project used `this->` for all member variable access, and think they where documenting hidden member variable access each time?

Comment: @Yakk:  I'd be confused why the powers that be selected such an illogical naming scheme, yes.  It would also be confusing when there actually *were* hidden names.  Imagine how hard it would be to find *that* bug, in a codebase where `this->` was SOP.

Comment: How would it be harder than in a codebase where `this->` was not SOP?  Compilers with decent warnings would still yell at you when you accessed a hiding variable.  Ifyou are saying that you should avoid hiding member variables, that is good advice.  But that is orthogonal to what the OP asked.

Answer (score 10):

In principle, accessing members via `this->` is a coding style that can help in making things clearer, but it seems to be a matter of taste.

However, you also seem to use prefixing members with `_` (underscore). I would say that is too much, you should go for either of the two styles.

Comment: You should not prefix anything with an underscore.

Comment: I usually suffix my members with underscores. Prefixing can lead to use of a reserved name.

Comment: @dan: It is perfectly fine to prefix members with a single underscore (if they don't start with a capital letter). These type of comments are called 'Cult Programming', indicate a misunderstanding of the rule and spread a misconception

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, The *as long as it doesn't start with a capital letter* part is why I suffix them. It doesn't interfere with any name other than that which already ends with an underscore, but that's absurd name usage if you ask me. People coming from places such as C# might feel inclined to mix styles of capital letter public members (properties) and underscore prefixing.

Comment: I'm aware of reserved names. But I like prefixing all private members with `_`. So if I type `this->_` auto-complete shows me all the private members in the current class.

Comment: @chris: If your coding guidelines determine that you don't start with capital letters it is fine. An advantage of prefixing rather than suffixing is that tools that with a single character you can filter in  the set of candidates for completion if your tool offers autocompletion, allowing a fast way of *finding* what members are there. At any rate, in our coding guidelines the prefix is a regular character followed by the underscore.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I agree it offers benefits without problems with guidelines in place. It's something that the level of benefits varies per person. `m_` is a perfectly valid prefix to introduce the benefits of autocompletion with if you want that without the possibility of using a reserved name. I could just never get used to typing `m_` before everything. Of course if I end up somewhere that requires me to change that habit, it's a different story :)

Comment: Thanks guys. While I normally don't use neither underscore suffixes nor prefixes, I learned something new about them.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there any reasons I shouldn't do this?

Yes, there is a reason why you shouldn't do this.

Referencing a member variable with `this->` is strictly *required* only when a name has been hidden, such as with:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void bang(int val);
    int val;
};

void Foo::bang(int val)
{
    val = val;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.val = 42;
    foo.bang(84);
    cout << foo.val;

}
```

The output of this program is `42`, not `84`, because in `bang` the member variable has been hidden, and `val = val` results in a no-op.  In this case, `this->` is required:

```
void Foo::bang(int val)
{
    this->val = val;
}
```

In other cases, using `this->` has no effect, so it is not needed.

That, in itself, is not a reason not to use `this->`.  The maintennance of such a program is however a reason not to use `this->`.

You are using `this->` as a means of documentation to specify that the vairable that follows is a member variable.  However, to most programmers, that's not what usign `this->` actually documents.  What using `this->` documents is:

> There is a name that's been hidden here, so I'm using a special
>   technique to work around that.

Since that's not what you wanted to convey, your documentation is broken.

Instead of using `this->` to document that a name is a member variable, use a rational naming scheme consistently where member variables and method parameters can never be the same.

**Edit**  Consider another illustration of the same idea.

Suppose in my codebase, you found this:

```
int main()
{
    int(*fn)(int) = pingpong;
    (fn)(42);
}
```

Quite an unusual construct, but being a skilled C++ programmer, you see what's happening here.  `fn` is a pointer-to-function, and being assigned the value of `pingpong`, whatever that is.  And then the function pointed to by `pingpong` is being called with the singe `int` value `42`. So, wondering why in the world you need such a gizmo, you go looking for `pingpong` and find this:

```
static int(*pingpong)(int) = bangbang;
```

Ok, so what's `bangbang`?

```
int bangbang(int val)
{
    cout << val;
    return val+1;
}
```

"Now, wait a sec.  What in the world is going on here?  Why do we need to create a pointer-to-function and then call through that?  Why not just call the function?  Isn't this the same?"

```
int main()
{
    bangbang(42);
}
```

Yes, it is the same.  The observable effects are the same.

Wondering if that's really all there is too it, you see:

```
/*  IMPLEMENTATION NOTE
 *
 *  I use pointers-to-function to call free functions
 *  to document the difference between free functions
 *  and member functions.
 */
```

So the only reason we're using the pointer-to-function is to show that the function being called is a free function 
and not a member function.

Does that seem like just a "matter of style" to you?  Because it seems like insanity to me.

Comment: `pingpong` should be `const`, no?

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm) you will find:

> Unless a class member name is hidden, using the class member name is equivalent to using         the class member name with the this pointer and the class member access operator (->).

Answer (score 4):

I think you do this backwards. You want the code to assure you that what happens is exactly what is expected.

Why add extra code to point out that nothing special is happening? Accessing class members in the member functions happen all the time. That's what would be expected. It would be much better to add extra info when it is *not* the normal things that happen.

In code like this

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    void setBar(int NewBar) 
    { Bar = NewBar; }
```

you ask yourself - "Where could the `Bar` come from?".

As this is a setter in a class, what would it set if not a class member variable?! If it wasn't, *then* there would be a reason to add a lot of info about what's actually going on here!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using a convention to signify that an identifer is a data member (although not one I would recommend), adding `this->` is simply redundant in almost all cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is a somewhat subjective question obvously. `this->` seems much more python-idiomatic than C++-idiomatic. There are only a handful of cases in C++ where the leading `this->` is required, dealing with names in parent template classes. In general if your code is well organized it will be obvious to the reader that it's a member or local variable (globals should just be avoided), and reducing the amount to be read may reduce complexity. Additionally you can use an optional style (I like trailing `_`) to indicate member variables.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually harm anything, but programmers experienced with OO will see it and find it odd. It's similarly surprising to see "yoda conditionals," ie `if (0 == x)`.

Comment: Are you saying "Yoda conditionals" are odd, or they are not odd?

Comment: Yoda ternary operations: `( a : b ? bool_expr )`