# How do I name members of a parent class (library) for readability in both parent and child classes?

Tags: c++, readability

I created a custom library that is usually used as a parent class.
After I used it for 1 month, I begin to face difficulty about its readability.

It is better described by a simplified real example.

### **Library Level**

There is my c++ library to manage Object in 2D space.

It has 2 classes : **Grid** (the space) and **GridMember** (object in space).

### Game-logic Level

I create a **Table** derived from **Grid**, and **Ball** derived from **GridMember**.

### Problem

When I want to call function of **Grid** from **Table** like this:-

```
Table* table=new Table();
table-> .... some Grid's function .... (ctrl-space)
```

If ALL **Grid**'s function name have some *unique signatures* e.g. all of them has prefix **grid_**,
... the code will gain higher readability.

As you can see, it is captivating:-

```
table->grid_add(new Ball());               //Grid's function member
table->grid_moveTo(ball1,VecInteger(3,4)); //Grid's function member
table->flip();                             //not Grid's function member
```

However, when look inside Grid.h, now it is very dirty.
Every variable/function of **Grid** now contains that **grid_**.

This is one of the worst symptom :-

```
class Grid{
    //--------- old version -------
    void move_grid_to_offset(){...} //move the world
    //^ I prefer this name to moveGridToOffset, because it is easier to read

    //--------- new version ---------
    void grid_move_grid_to_offset(){...} 
    //^ After a long day, I read it as  grid......grid(again)..  
    //         not sure what it is doing
}
```

Therefore readability is reduced.

### Question

How to achieve high readability in both places?

Similar question : [Why use prefixes on member variables in C++ classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228161/why-use-prefixes-on-member-variables-in-c-classes) but it is not related to this problem.

Comment: `Table* table=new Table();` written like a true java lover :) C++ doesn't require you to `new` everything. In fact, in most cases you shouldn't and just hurt the maintainability and efficiency of your code.

Comment: :D, it is my bad habit, I know I can Table table;

Comment: If you don't mind repeating yourself, you can add a bunch of inline short wrappers. The non member `grid_move_to_offset(Grid&, /*params*/)` will do c++11 perfect forwarding to `Grid::move_to_offset`

Comment: You really should become re-accustomed to value semantics and auto storage when writing c++. It makes life so much easier in the long run.

Comment: Yes, I accept that I am careless.   Now for you solution.  I am interested, if you don't mind, please provide more detail.  I have looked into namespace, but it can't be used inside class.

Comment: The solution I have in mind is something akin to `inline void grid_func1(const Grid& grid) { grid.func1(); }`. Not really pleasant, but gives you flexibility. Another thing you should reconsider, is if a `Table` **really is** a `Grid`. Because IMHO, it shouldn't matter where the member function originates. Any decent code explorer will take you the right place anyway.

Comment: Just drop all the prefixes. Not needed in the slightest. If you find `table->move` less intuitive than either `grid->move` or `table->grid_move`, you probably should have not used inheritance in this case. Evaluate containment instead. As the last resort, write `Grid* Table::grid() { return this; }` and use `table->grid()->move`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any member of a subclass should actually be a member of any superclass, conceptually as well as programatically.  Thus, in this case, any Table actually is a Grid, and any Ball actually is a GridMember.  Since a Table is a Grid, Table->add() should be perfectly clear, without worrying about whether it's a Grid function or a Table function.

In the case of move_grid_to_offset, the issue is not that there's too little information in the name, but that there's already too much:  a better name would be move_to_offset or offset_by.  Since you already know that it's a grid whose member function is being invoked, it's unnecessary to repeat in the name of the member function that it applies to the grid:  grid.offset_by() is perfectly clear.  And table.offset_by() is also perfectly clear, even if we don't know about the Grid class at all.