# C++, template, compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't a derived template class have access to a base template class' identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239908/why-doesnt-a-derived-template-class-have-access-to-a-base-template-class-identi)

Translating of the following program

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
template <class T>
class A
{
  protected :
    T a;
  public:
    A(): a(0) {}
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
template <class T>
class A;

template <class T>
class B: public A <T>
{
  protected:
    T b;

  public:
    B() : A<T>(), b(0) {}
    void test () { b = 2 * a;}   //a was not declared in this scope
};
#endif
```

causes an error: "a was not declared in this scope". (Netbeans 6.9.1).

But the construction

```
void test () { b = 2 * this->a;}
```

is correct... Where is  the problem?

Is it better to use forward declaration or file include directive?

B.h

```
template <class T>
class A;
```

vs.

```
#include "A.h"
```

Comment: Read http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#whythisarrow

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't a derived template class have access to a base template class' identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239908/why-doesnt-a-derived-template-class-have-access-to-a-base-template-class-identi)

Answer (score 0):

`A<T>::a` is a dependent name, so you can't use it unqualified.

Imagine that there was a specialization of `A<int>` somewhere:

```
template<> class A<int> { /* no a defined */ };
```

What should the compiler do now?  Or what if `A<int>::a` was a function instead of a variable?

Qualify your access to `a`, as you've already discovered `this->a`, and things will work right.

Comment: Oh how I love being downvoted with no explanation :(

Comment: Your answer is correct. Upvoted to counterbalance.