# C++, templates, static functions

Tags: c++, templates, function, static

My question concerns the templates again... From my static template function "functionA" in non template class A

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "B.h"
class A
{
  template <class T>
  static T functionA();

};

template <class T>
T A::functionA()
{
     T var;
     T result = B::functionB(var); //Class B has not been declared
}

#endif
```

I am calling static template function "function B" declared and defined inside non template class B. Before the class A declaration class B has already been included...

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
class B
{
  template <class T>
  static T functionB(T var) ;
};

template<class T>
T B::functionB(T var)
{
   ...some code
}
#endif
```

During the compilation of the program the following error message has been apperared:

//Class B has not been declared

This is not a real code, only example for the ilustration. This situation has appeared calling some static methods i my program. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Err.. what's the question? The examples you've posted should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find an actual question in here.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Also your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540106/c-template-compiler-error-closed) was closed because it was a duplicate. Adding another duplicate isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: This is no longer an exact duplicate because neither class inherits the other.

Comment: Works: http://codepad.org/AslttNHe

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem with the code posted is that the functions are not declared as being public.  Also, functionA is not returning a value.

The following code will execute properly.

**file A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static T functionA();
};

template <class T>
T A::functionA()
{
     T var = 4;
     T result = B::functionB(var); //Class B has not been declared
     return result;
}

#endif
```

**file B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
class B
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static T functionB(T var) ;
};

template<class T>
T B::functionB(T var)
{
  var++;
  return var;
}
#endif
```

**file main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = A::functionA<int>();
  printf("result: %i\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
result: 5
```