# Is there another workaround for template base class inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc

This code produces an error in the GNU compiler:

```
class A
{
public:
    int X;
};

template<class T>
class Foo : public T
{
public:
    void doStuff();
};

template<class T>
void Foo<T>::doStuff()
{
    X++;
}
```

There is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239908/why-doesnt-a-derived-template-class-have-access-to-a-base-template-class-identi) for why this is an error. I would like to know if there is another way of working around this error rather than using

```
T::X
```

every time I want to reference the X member. I tried this:

```
template<class T>
void Foo<T>::doStuff()
{
    using T::X;
    X++;
}
```

But GCC gives an error: "a class-qualified name is not allowed"

Comment: obviously you cannot do `using T::X;` inside the function. You need to do this as shown here : http://www.ideone.com/MI9fM ... see my answer for other alternatives. They're not as good as this, but being aware of them helps sometimes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`using T::X`](http://www.ideone.com/MI9fM) should work. If it gives error, there is some *other* problem with your code, or it must be compiler bug. See yourself : http://www.ideone.com/MI9fM

---

- You may use `this` pointer, as

  ```
  template<class T>
  void Foo<T>::doStuff()
  {
      this->X++;
  }
  ```

  This gives compiler a hint where to look for the  symbol  `X`.

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/NIucO

---

- You can also do this:

  ```
  template<class T>
  void Foo<T>::doStuff()
  {
       T::X++;
  }
  ```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/PswvG

Answer (score 3):

This would also work:

```
this->X++;
```

That would tell the compiler than since it sees X is not a member of the derived class, it has to come from the template base and there is no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
public:
    int X;
};

template<class T>
class Foo : public T
{
public:
    using T::X;
    void doStuff();
};

template<class T>
void Foo<T>::doStuff()
{
    X++;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<A> o;
    o.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was missing, I put the using T::X in the doStuff() function instead of the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?  Just guessing:

```
int &X = T::X;
```

This will create an alias that can be used within a block of code, similarly to the `using T::X` you tried that didn't work.