# Why base function cannot be accessed by derived class when involving template classes

Tags: c++, templates

The following code is giving compilation error:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
    void bar(){};
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
    public:
    void foo() { bar(); }   //Error
};

int main()
{
    Derived *b = new Derived;
    b->foo();
}
```

**ERROR**

`Line 12: error: there are no arguments to 'bar' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'bar' must be available`

Why is this error coming?

Comment: As a side note: You did not specify the template parameter for `Derived` in `main()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a derived template class have access to a base template class' identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239908/why-doesnt-a-derived-template-class-have-access-to-a-base-template-class-ident)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name `foo()` does not depend on any of `Derived`'s template parameters - it's a *non-dependent* name. The base class where `foo()` is found, on the other hand - `Base<T>` - *does* depend on one of `Derived`'s template parameters (namely, `T`), so it's a *dependent base class*. C++ does not look in dependent base classes when looking up non-dependent names.

To resolve this, you need to qualify the call to `bar()` in `Derived::foo()` as either `this->bar()` or `Base<T>::bar()`.

This C++ FAQ item explains it nicely: see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19

Comment: I always saw this as a short-coming of C++. In Python, the extra-qualification `self.` before attributes and methods may seem verbose, but it's consistent, so people are used to it. In C++ `this->` is optional... so people forget when it's really necessary... all in the name of saving 5 characters :x

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I used to think this behaviour (and many other things related to name lookup in C++) was annoying, too, but there are good reasons for it. A dependent name lookup is more expensive for the compiler than a non-dependent name lookup, because the lookup needs to be delayed until template instantiation time, and performed separately for each instantiation. So, by default, non-dependent name lookup is performed for names that don't mention template parameters, and you have the option of making the lookup dependent by adding `this->`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: [continued] This is consistent with the C++ design principle of "don't pay for what you don't use". It's similar to how functions are by default non-virtual, and you have the option of making them virtual (another behaviour that some find annoying), except for virtual functions the cost in question is a runtime cost, whereas for name lookup the cost in question is a compile-time cost.

Comment: Oh, I am not bashing on the template mechanism. I am bashing on inconsistencies in the syntax. The *sometimes* `this->` is necessary is hard to grok. And imagine what would happen if you had a free function named `bar` ? It would get picked up, even though in classes normally methods have priority over free functions. My opinion is that *requiring* `this->` for all method calls would make for a much more regular syntax.

Comment: there is no rule in c++ that nondependent names are not looked up in dependent base classes. the rule is that unqualified names are not looked up inbdependent base classes.

Comment: Here's the rule: the compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like B<T>) when looking up nondependent names (like Xyz or Pqr). As a result, the compiler does not know they even exist let alone are types. Taken from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

Comment: @MatthieuM.: My point is, *requiring* `this->` for all method calls would make all methods calls in a template dependent, giving the compiler unnecessary work. (In an extreme case, consider a template with 999 nondependent names and 1 dependent name, instantiated 1000 times. It matters whether the nondependent names are each looked up once or 1000 times).

Comment: @litb: Could you give an example of a name that is qualified but nondependent and is looked up in dependent base classes?

Comment: @high the very fact of trying to look something up in the dependent baseclass with a qualified name makes the name dependent. so there is no example for what you ask for. but nondependent unqualified names *could* look into the dependent base class if it waits for the lookup until instantiation. however the standard says that the binding of nondependent names must be fixed at parsing time. so if there would not be the rule that unqualified names are not looked up in dependent base classes, you would have a classic case of undefined behavior by omission of descriptikn of behavior.

Comment: note that the binding being known at parse time does not imply to ignore dependent base classes. it could mean to emit a diagnostic for being unable to look things up in a dependent base class before substitution took place for a dependent base class.

Comment: @HighCommander4: I disagree about `this->` requiring to defer look-up to instantiation. `this->foo()` only indicates *`foo` is a method*. If you can find the method right when parsing the template, great for you! If not, you need to wait until instantiation, but that's what you would have to do anyway.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I would image there are cases when trying a nondependent lookup and if it fails doing a dependent lookup at instantiation would yield different results from just doing a dependent lookup at instantiation in the first place. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided doesn't have a build error on the line you indicate.  It DOES have one here:

```
Derived *b = new Derived;
```

which should read:

```
Derived<int> *b = new Derived<int>();
```

(or use whatever type you want instead of int.)

Comment: It *does* have an error on the line OP says, as well as the error you pointed out.

Comment: @cppcoder well it solves ONE issue.  As for the qualification mentioned in the answer above, it seems your compiler is dumber/more compliant/pickier than mine!  :-)

Comment: @user1158692: More compliant is the correct choice. To be compliant, a compiler must barf at that unqualified reference to `bar()`.