# c++ static polymorphism / CRTP with additional template parameters accessing base class member

Tags: c++, templates, static-polymorphism

I would like to implement static polymorphism using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and also add additional types to the templates parameters.

Providing the following scenario, how can I directly access Base members from a Derived class? Is it possible without specifying the full type of the Base class?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived, class X>
struct Base
{
    void set_a( int a ) { _a = a; }
    protected:
        int _a;
};

template<class X>
struct Derived: public Base<Derived<X>, X>
{
    int get_a( )
    {
        // return Base<Derived<X>,X>::_a; // This works!
        return _a; // error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'
    }
};

struct foo;

int main()
{
    Derived<foo> test;

    auto base_p = static_cast< Base<Derived<foo>, foo>* >( &test );
    base_p->set_a( 42 );

    int a = test.get_a();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

g++5.3.1 / clang++3.8.0 output:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `using` declaration in your class:

```
template<class X>
struct Derived: public Base<Derived<X>, X> {

  using Base<Derived<X>, X>::_a;

  /* ... */

};
```

You still have to specify it once though.

Comment: Nice workaround! But i would like to understand why I have to specify it once!

Comment: @Albert You have to specify it because your base class is dependent on a template parameter of your class.

Comment: Ok. Now @Holt found the real problem, I've found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239908/why-doesnt-a-derived-template-class-have-access-to-a-base-template-class-ident

Answer (score 1):

In `Derived` scope, `_a` is not declared but inherited, so you have to write `this->_a` to look up in a base class or explicitly write `Base<Derived<X>, X>::_a`.  The latter can be imported with

```
using Base<Derived<X>, X>::_a;
```

in the definition of `Derived`.

**tl;dr**

If `this->_a` is written, `this` is automatically up-cast to `Base<Derived<X>, X>*` to match the intrinsic `operator->`.

If only `_a` is written, an [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) is performed.  An unqualified name lookup is scope-based, which is unrelated to inheritance.  In your example, the `_a` is in `Derived::get_a`, so `_a` is searched in

- `Derived::get_a`
- `Derived`
- (File scope)

No `_a` is found, which triggers a compile error.

Comment: I like the fact that your tl;dr section is longer than the supposedly long answer, because it x'D