# template base class typedef members invisible

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, dependent-name

I'm aware of the fact that the 'dependent names' are not visible to the compiler by default.  But I was told in answers to other SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514673/cant-access-members-of-a-template-base-class-within-a-derived-template-class), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data), and ultimately [on the C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html)) that a `using` declaration may help.

So I tried.

A template base class:

```
// regardless of the fact that members are exposed...
template<typename T>
struct TBase {
   typedef T MemberType;
   MemberType baseMember;
   MemberType baseFunction() { return MemberType(); }
};
```

And a derived class, using the base's members:

```
template<typename T>
struct TDerived : public TBase<T> {
   // http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html
   // tells us to use a `using` declaration.
   using typename TBase<T>::MemberType;
   using TBase<T>::baseFunction;
   using TBase<T>::baseMember;

   void useBaseFunction() { 
      // this goes allright.
      baseFunction();
      ++baseMember;

      // but here, the compiler doesn't want to help...
      MemberType t; //error: expected `;' before ‘t’
   }
};
```

I tried [this out on ideone](http://ideone.com/iUsXKG). It has gcc-4.3.3 and gcc-4.5.1

Is this expected behavior?  How are we supposed to work around the 'dependent name' law for accessing parent template class' member typedefs?

Comment: This happens because of the two-phase name lookup (which not all compilers use by default).  There are 4 solutions to this problem: **1)** Use the prefix `TBase<T>::baseMember`, **2)** Use the prefix `this->baseMember`, **3)** Add a statement `using TBase<T>::baseMember`, **4)** Use a global compiler switch that enables the permissive mode.  The pros & cons and details of these solutions are described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321788/a-better-way-to-avoid-public-member-invisibility-and-source-code-bloat-repetitio

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably want to do:

```
using MemberType = typename TBase<T>::MemberType; // new type alias syntax
```

or

```
typedef typename TBase<T>::MemberType MemberType; // old type alias syntax
```

The syntax `using Base::member;` can only be used to bring the declarations of non-type members into scope.

---

Also note that none of these are actually required, you can qualify each use (for types with the base, for non-types with either `this->` or the base) and that will make the symbol dependent.

Comment: Was stuck with this issue. Came across your answer and using "this->" in the derived class worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: actually, you may use using syntax but need typename `using typename TBase<T>::MemberType;` seem to work for me