# Local declaration from an inherited struct not recognised

Tags: c++, templates

```
template< int a, int b >
struct aa {
  template< int x, int y >
  struct att { int axx[ a + x ][ b + y ]; };
};   

struct b1 : public aa< 1, 2 > {
  typedef att< 1, 2 > x;
};

template< int q >
struct b2 : public aa< 12, q > {
    typedef att< 1, 2 > x;
};
```

b1 compiles without a problem (GCC 4.8), but b2 complains

```
error: 'att' does not name a type
typedef att< 1, 2 > x;
        ^
```

why??

Comment: Try `using aa<1, 2>::att<1, 2>;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data)

Comment: More like `typedef typename aa<12,q>::template att< 1, 2 > x;`. What a mouthful! See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think that's needed as `b1` and `b2` aren't templates.... :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 `b2` is a template.

Comment: @juanchopanza: make that an answer! But it is an ugly mouthful :) is there a good way to shorten it? My real code has ~ 30 such lines. (yes, it should be 'b2 cmplains')

Comment: I think all the information is in the second link, which is a better duplicate than the first one. So I will abstain from answering.

Answer (score 1):

Because non-dependent names such as `att<1,2>` are not looked up in dependent base classes (like `aa<12,q>`, which depends on `q`).

In the case of `b1`, the base class `aa<1,2>` is not a dependent base, so everything works fine. For `b2`, the easiest way is to write `typename aa<12,q>::template att<1,2>`.

For a relevant reference, see section 9.4.2 (Dependent Base Classes) in C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (Vandevoorde and Josuttis).