# Template Class derived from Non-template base class: No access to base class variables?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following class structure:

```
class Base {
public:
    std::set<Index> openIndices;
    Base() {};
};


template<typename lhs_t, typename rhs_t>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    lhs_t &lhs;
    rhs_t &rhs;

    Derived(lhs_t &_lhs, rhs_t &_rhs) : 
            Base(), 
            lhs(_lhs),
            rhs(_rhs),
            openIndices(std::set_symmetric_difference(lhs.openIndices, rhs.openIndices)) 
    {
    }
};
```

So basicly a template Class `Derived`derived from the base class `Base`. When accessing the member variables ob the baser class I get the following error:

```
test.h:34:88: error: class ‘Derived<lhs_t, rhs_t>’ does not have any field named ‘openIndices’
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120833/991425): I cannot access the member variables in case my class is derived from a template class. But in my case I am not derived from a template class, still I can't access the member variables. Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cant initialize member variables of a base class. You have to provide an appropriate constructor in the base class and call this constructor.

Comment: Omg, yea I should have known this! Obviously I was too confused by the templates in my true code. Thanks anyway.