# Inheritance with template classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to figure out, how can I inherit from template class to template class. The problem is: I can't use protected members of Parent class.

Example:

```
template <class N>
class Parent {
protected:
    N member;
public:
    Parent(N aa){
        member = aa;
    }
};


class Child1: public Parent<int>{
    public:
        Child1(int a): Parent<int>(a) {
            member += 1; // works
        }
};

template<class Q>
class Child2: public Parent<Q>{
    public:
        Child2(int a): Parent<Q>(a) {
            member += 1; // does not work (use of undeclared identifier)
        }
};
```

How can I use "member" in the Child2 class?

Thanks for your time

Comment: `this->member` will work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245777/access-static-member-of-template-parent-class) explains it, though the origin was about static members the reason is still the same, and includes links to additional explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this->member` or `Parent<Q>::member`.

In the second case, `member` is a "[dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)" because the existence of `member` from the base class template `Parent<Q>` depends on the type of `class Q` in the template, whereas in the first example there is no dependent type, the compiler can statically analyze that `Parent<int>` contains `member`.