# Accessing base member data error when derived class is templated

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following problem with the curiously recurring template, with a problem when I try to access the data member of CRTP base class.

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
  int protectedData=10;
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
  void method() {
    std::cout<<protectedData<<std::endl;
  };
};

int main ()
{
  Derived a;
  a.method();
}
```

The above code compiles and runs fine and I can get "10" printed, but if I have the derived class templated, like:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
  int protectedData=10;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived<T> > {
public:
  void method() {
    std::cout<<protectedData<<std::endl;
  };
};

class A{};

int main ()
{
  Derived<A> a;
  a.method();
}
```

class A is just a dummy class served as the template parameter. But the compiler complains cannot find the "protectedData". The error information is as following:

```
g++-4.9 test.cc -Wall -std=c++1y -Wconversion -Wextra
test.cc: In member function ‘void Derived<T>::method()’:
test.cc:26:11: error: ‘protectedData’ was not declared in this scope
    cout<<protectedData<<endl;
```

Comment: Does it work if you reference the member using the base classes name? `Base<Derived<T> >::protectedMember`

Comment: Try providing the full scope to the variable.

Comment: `this->protectedData`. Name lookup for `protectedData` doesn't look into dependent base classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really have to do with CRTP, but rather with the fact that for dependent-base-accessing derived code, you need to qualify things.

Changing the line to

```
std::cout<<this->protectedData<<std::endl;
```

solved it.

See [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data).

Comment: @PiotrS. You're right, of course. Thanks. Corrected the phrasing.