# Template class: static members not inherited

Tags: c++, templates

The following code

```
template<int c>
struct Base
{
    static const int a = c + 5;
};

template<int c>
struct Derived : Base<c>
{
    static const int b = a + 5;
};
```

... fails to compile because `a was not declared in this scope`. Explicitly specifying `Base<c>::a` works, but logically this shouldn't be necessary because we're deriving from `Base<c>`. Is this intended behaviour (and why) or am I missing something?

Comment: @ TartanLlama although that duplicate does not explain why this works in MSVC

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour from the third answer: "Actually, VC doesn't do two-phase lookup. That's why it compiles there. And that's why it is a bad idea to create a template lib using VC -- you'll have a lot of stuff to fix when you need it on any other compiler."

Comment: @TartanLlama somewhat dubious to rely on comment since they are not meant to stick around but don't have time to think about it now.

Answer (score -4):

```
template<int c>
struct Derived : Base<c>
{
    static const int b = Base<c>::a + 5;
};
```

It really depends on compiler, but gcc requires it, it plays stupid when it comes to template classes

Comment: It does not depend on a compiler. From what i've seen it will work in MSVC  but this is because of extensions.

Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data

Comment: You have repeated exactly the solution already mentioned in the question, but you haven't explained *why* it's necessary. Your only original contribution is to call the compiler stupid, which is not constructive. You have not answered the question.

Comment: riodoro1  - MSVC works not because of the "extension", it just works because developers of the compiler decided it is something that should work.

Comment: Rob Kennedy -  I said it plays stupid, not the same thing. The exact explanation from gcc something like - it is difficult to resolve base classes members, or some bs like that . We struggle with this behavior since gcc 3.x. MSVC never had the problem , nor , I believe, does  Borland