# How to initialize inherited templated POD struct in derived class portably?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, visual-c++, portability

I encountered a problem when I tried to compile my program on GCC and am interested in knowing how to portably initialize an inherited POD struct using C++11's initializing syntax `e.g. struct { int a; int b} my_struct {1, 2}`. The problem can be represented minimally with the following code which compiles fine on MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename A>
struct base {
 A a;
};

template <typename A>
class derived : public base<A> {
public:
  derived();
};

template <typename A>
derived<A>::derived() : base {1} {

  std::cout << "Constructed " << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  derived<int> d1;
}
```

However, GCC with C++14 enabled roughly states that `derived<A>` does not have any field 'base'. So I try the following change.

```
template <typename A>
derived<A>::derived() : base<A> {1} {

  std::cout << "Constructed " << a << std::endl;
}
```

GCC now recognizes `base<A>` as a field of `derived<A>` fine, but states that `a` is not declared in this scope.

Funnily enough this change now doesn't compile on MSVC and states "'{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)".

At this point I have no idea how to write this in a standard compliant way.

Thanks.

Comment: it compiles on my VS15....

Comment: ...but not his last example, this only works in VS15 when replacing `: base<A>` by `: base`.

Comment: I'm talking about the last example with `base<A>`. (VS15 update 3)

Comment: @ZivS Huh, that's strange. Does MVSC15 fail to compile the `base<A>` version for someone else than me?

Comment: Re using `this->a` vs just `a`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes your last example work:

```
std::cout << "Constructed " << this->a << std::endl;
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe9715a447ffbea1

At first I couldn't compile it under MSVC++ 2015 (update 1). After installing [update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) it compiles fine.

Comment: Why on earth is this-> necessary on GCC? Regardless, the portability problem remains.

Comment: It seems like you have found an edge case that's barely supported by either compiler.

Comment: Just checked... I'm still on update 1. I will now install update 3 to check if this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

C++17 will support this in some form:

Form [aggregate_initialization:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

> Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

```
// aggregate
struct base1 { int b1, b2 = 42; };
// non-aggregate
struct base2 {
  base2() : b3(42) {}
  int b3;
};
// aggregate in C++17
struct derived : base1, base2 { int d; };
derived d1{ {1, 2}, { }, 4}; // d1.b1 = 1, d1.b2 = 2,  d1.b3 = 42, d1.d = 4
derived d2{ {    }, { }, 4}; // d2.b1 = 0, d2.b2 = 42, d2.b3 = 42, d2.d = 4
```

Meanwhile a standard way would be:

```
template <typename A>
    derived<A>::derived()  {
        this->a = 1;
}
```