# C++: gcc: error was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc

Can somebody explain why gcc throws:

lst_iterators.h: In member function â€LST::CIterators::Iterator_Forward& LST::CIterators::Iterator_Forward::operator++()â€™:
lst_iterators.h:77:7: error: â€m_pDataâ€™ was not declared in this scope
     ++m_pData;

1. Everything works properly in VS2017, but gcc complains.
2. As can be seen m_pData is a normal variable in Iterator_Base class, so why can't gcc see the base class?
3. I'm using Centos 7.2 and gcc 6.3.

Any help is appreciated.

Br
Waldemar

```
template <typename itemType> class CIterators
{
    public: class Iterator_Base
    {
    //Constructor/Destructor
        public: Iterator_Base( itemType* pData ) : m_pData( pData )
        {
        };

        protected: itemType*        m_pData;

    //Operators
        public: itemType& operator*()
        {
        //Value operator -> return reference.
            return *m_pData;
        };
        public: bool operator!=( const Iterator_Base& iterator ) const
        {
        //Not equal operator -> compare if not at same pointer.
            return ( m_pData != iterator.m_pData );
        };
    };
    public: class Iterator_Forward : public Iterator_Base
    {
    //Constructor/Destructor
        public: Iterator_Forward( itemType* pData ) : Iterator_Base( pData )
        {
        };

    //Operators
        public: Iterator_Forward& operator++()
        {
        //Increment operator -> go to next value (increase pointer).
            ++m_pData;

        //Return reference.
            return *this;
        };
    };
};
```

Edit:
I still don't understand why gcc doesn't see or know about the base class, but Kerrek's solution works ok.

```
        public: Iterator_Forward& operator++()
        {
        //Increment operator -> go to next value (increase pointer).
            ++this->m_pData;

        //Return reference.
            return *this;
        };
```

Edit2:
Also found the same issue at [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data) . Maybe a better solution then this-> is to define which variables are used from base class.

```
    public: class Iterator_Forward : public Iterator_Base
    {
        protected: using Iterator_Base::m_pData;

    //Constructor/Destructor
        public: Iterator_Forward( itemType* pData ) : Iterator_Base( pData )
        ...
```

Comment: Is gcc really writing these strange characters or is it just a misprint in a question text?

Comment: Stop annotating everything with an access specifier. It's not Java.

Comment: Looks like `m_pData` is dependent, so it cannot be used unqualified during the first phase. Say `this->m_pData` instead. MSVC does not implement two-phase lookup correctly as far as I know.

Comment: The error in your title is completely different from the error in your body.

Comment: Alex: I assume it's a codepage issue when working from Wins to Linux through shell... I'm so used to it, that I don't see it anymore.

Comment: Molbdnilo: As I'm programing for 30 years, have seen a lot of code which ranged from beauty to pure shit and have worked with multiple languages. So I have taken best from every one and created my own coding style which is much, much, much more descriptive, transparent and beautiful then other (for example lately I'm also working with Qt library which is pure horror to me, so I've finally decided that I'll ditch it and create my own).

Comment: Kerrek: Thanks for the idea, but it still doesn't work... I'll dig deeper.

Comment: BoundaryImposition: Thanks for the notice... have fix it.

Comment: Kerrek: After changing some other derived classes your this-> idea worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: Alex: Changed the codepage to UTF8 and now there is ‘ characters instead of garbage.