# Why does accessing a protected member in a template subclass require the parent classes prefix?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, protected

```
template <class T>
class Parent {
protected:
  T _value;
};

template <class T>
class Child : public Parent<T> {
public:
  void doStuff() { std::cout << _value << std::endl; }
};
```

GCC 6.3 gives

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void Child<T>::doStuff()’:
prog.cpp:14:33: error: ‘_value’ was not declared in this scope
   void doStuff() { std::cout << _value << std::endl; }
                                 ^~~~~~
```

Using `Parent<T>::_value` instead of `_value` works. Why?

Reason for my confusion is that making `Child` not a template works, too.

```
class Child : public Parent<int> {
public:
  void doStuff() { std::cout << _value << std::endl; }
};
```

---

PS: On a side note, it compiles fine with MSVC in any case. I suspect that that is MSVC's fault, though.

Comment: Templates are special. [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120833/3309790)

Comment: The last example works because `Parent<int>` is not a template.