# In constructo error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I don't know that why the son class can't use the variable from the parent class. I used to use java but it does not occur in Java. I am a c++ beginner;

---

the parent class

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class List{
protected:
    int length;
    T *data;
public:
    List() {
        length = 0;
        data = nullptr;
        std::cout << "父类构造函数..." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~List() {
        length = 0;
        data = nullptr;
        std::cout << "父类析构函数..." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

the son class

```
#include "List.h"

template<class T>
class ArrayList : public List<T> {
private:
    const int INIT_SIZE = 10;
    const int INCREMENT_SIZE = 10;

    int maxSize;


public:
    ArrayList() {
        std::cout << "子类构造函数..." << std::endl;
        data = new T[INIT_SIZE];
        maxSize = INIT_SIZE;
    }

    virtual ~ArrayList() {
        std::cout << "子类析构函数..." << std::endl;
        maxSize = 0;
    }
}
```

---

error:

```
In constructor ‘ArrayList<T>::ArrayList()’:

error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
         data = new T[INIT_SIZE];
         ^~~~
```

It also occurred on the variable 'length' which in the son's functions.

Comment: Try `this->data = ...`.

Comment: See [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368629/3309790) for more.

Comment: thanks! Because I must write data struct in C/C++ but I used to use Java and I am a c++ beginner. I'll go to have a see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this->data` . This should fix your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [C++ Super FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

> - Change the call from `f()` to `this->f()`. Since this is always implicitly dependent in a template, this->f is dependent and the lookup is therefore deferred until the template is actually instantiated, at which point all base classes are considered.
> - Insert `using B<T>::f;` just prior to calling `f()`.
> - Change the call from `f()` to `B<T>::f()`. Note however that this might not give you what you want if f() is virtual, since it inhibits the virtual dispatch mechanism.