# inheriting from a template class: "member" was not declared at this scope

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
template<typename T> class A {
protected:
    int member;
};

template<typename T> class B : public A<T> {
    B() {
        member = 12;
    }
};
```

When I try to compile the above program, I get:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘B<T>::B()’:
test.cpp:8:9: error: ‘member’ was not declared in this scope
         member = 12;
         ^~~~~~
```

I know how to solve the problem. I just change `member=12` to `this->member=12`. My question is: why does the compiler not compile this?

I'll point out that the error is issued despite the fact that the template have not been instantiated in any way. It's just two classes defined, still in template form.

Comment: not sure if this explains the "why" enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data see the second top answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a name in a way that doesn't reference the template parameter visually, it should absolutely *not* depend on the template parameter!

```
void foo();

template <typename T>
struct A : T {
    void bar() {
        foo();
    }
};
```

It could be very bad that if `T` has a `foo` member function then the call resolves to the member and not to the global function.

If there is no global `foo` you could argue that it could resolve to a member function/data member as fallback, but that would complicate the language and could be confusing to get right ("I want to call member `foobar` but I didn't realize that there was a global function that happens to have the right signature").

In your example someone could specialize `A` with no `member` data member. Would a hypothetical global `member` variable be used instead? With `this->` it's unambiguous.

Comment: or also `T::foo()`