# Public class member not visible when CRTP derived type is a template class

Tags: c++, templates

The below code doesn't compile.

I want `Derived<T>` to access `m_vec` member of `Base`. However, because `Derived<T>` is templated, it implemented CRTP via `: public Base<Derived<T>>` and `m_vec` is not visible.

If I change `Derived<T>` to just `Derived`, `m_vec` becomes visible.

Why is this/is there a workaround?

```
#include <vector>

template<class SUB_CLASS>
struct Base
{
    Base(int config){}
    std::vector<std::string> m_vec;  
};

template<class T>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived<T>>
{
    Derived(int config) : Base<Derived<T>>(config){}
    
    void start()
    {
        m_vec.clear();   // This line doesn't compile. m_vec is not accessible
    }
};

int main()
{
    int config = 0;
    Derived<int> d(config);
    d.start();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the member using

```
this->m_vec.clear();
```

That should compile.

Comment: See here to understand the solution better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data